# .htaccess rewrite file path to folder path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a subdirectory contact and inside contact.php and contact_content.php and .htaccess file

In .htaccess file I have following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/contact.php
RewriteRule ^ /contact [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/$ contact.php [NC,L,END] 

# deny access
RewriteRule ^(contact_content)\.php - [F,L,NC]
```

Deny access part and the first rewrite rule work perfectly but
the problem is the second rewriterule-> when I go to `localhost/contact` I am shown the list of files in contact directory instead of `contact.php` site

Comment: Hope my current post will work fine., I have tested in all the cases which you are refering

Comment: Partially did, I will put code which works for me now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me-> modified Sahil Gulati answer

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/contact.php
RewriteRule ^ /contact [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /contact/contact.php [L,QSA,END]

RewriteRule ^(contact_content)\.php - [F,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it will work fine.

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} contact\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /contact [R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/contact.php [L,QSA,END]

RewriteRule ^(contact_content)\.php - [F,L,NC]
```

Comment: so what you want in that case when user type `/contact`

Comment: so when user type /contact I want to be shown contact.php page

Comment: @MPavic you want to execute `/contact/contact.php` when user hit `/contact` and for `contact_content.php` you want to forbid right?

Comment: yes, that is correct-> current forbidd works great, even redirect works if user directly goes to /contact/contact.php it redirects him to /contact