# Using apache mod_rewrite to redirect to php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/food/?p=11&q=22&r=33
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/food/api.php/DBNAME/?p=11&q=22&r=33
```

As you may have noticed, `DBNAME` is the name of a database.
With the API I'm using it is necessary to include it in the URL.

Here's a brief folder structure of my program:

```
food/
   ->include/
   ->models/
   ->.htaccess
   ->api.php
   ->config.php
   ->test.php
```

I tried writing the rules on the .htaccess file but I get an `Internal server` error.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php/DBNAME/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can get my head around achieving the redirection.
I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^food/(.*)$ api.php/DBNAME/$1 [L]
```

but this rule just lists the files in the directory food.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

PS: The query string is not just `p=11&q=22&r=33` it may use any letter or word such as type, quantity and so on. `p=11&q=22&r=33` is just an example.

**Edit**
From the link that @sanj provided I changed my .htaccess ffile to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/food/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php/DBNAME/$1
</IfModule>
```

It works partially. Why partially?

I have two servers, one for testing and one for production. It works well on the testing server but not on the production server. I get an `Authorization Required` error. I believe it's due to the configuration in my .htaccess because if I remove the mod_rewrite module and access the url directly it works. Any ideas?

Found my mistake. The folder was protected by Basic Authentication. I needed to include login parameters in my code. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342312/htaccess-rewrite-file-path-to-folder-path have a look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /food
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /DBNAME/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
    RewriteRule ^$                index.php/DBNAME/?%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still got the same Internal Server error.

Comment: I forget to add [QSA,L], `RewriteRule (.*)    api.php/DBNAME/$1 [QSA,L]` . You can find a complete reference here: [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)

Comment: I also forgot this the `?p=`, sorry. this works for me:  `RewriteRule (.*)    api.php/DBNAME/?p=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Tried it but same error. By the way, can you modify your original answer to reflect the changes you just described?

Comment: The answer has been modified. I realized that [QSA,L] is not necessary. Your .htaccess file is only this: 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteBase /food
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule (.*)                     api.php/DBNAME/?p=$1
    </IfModule>

Comment: I think the way you are including DBNAME in the URL is causing the Internal server error. Is there another way to include it? you can try this: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /food
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /DBNAME/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.*)
    RewriteRule ^$       index.php/DBNAME/?p=%1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Can you explain why you're using `p=(.*)`?
Forgot to mention it but actually, my query string is not just `p=11&q=22&r=33` it may use any letter or word such as `type`, `quantity` and so on. `p=11&q=22&r=33` is just an example.

Comment: oh, ok. I changed the answer to accept all parameters

Comment: Thanks for your help! Tried your suggestion but it lists the contents of the directory `food`. It works if I comment `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /DBNAME/` though. Any ideas why?